# Run Script After On Current

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am sure this is really simple but i just cant make it work. I have a form with three sub forms. The main form loads and finds the requested record fine and if i run the below from a button on the main form it works fine. What i want to do is have it run after form loads requested record and with out user interaction. I have tried on load and on current but as the form is not yet on screen there are no values to populate the variables and the msgboxes are blank. But like i said fired from a button on the main it works fine.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
actCount = [ActMovDelete].Form![Text93].Value
PlaCount = [PalnMovDelete].Form![Text91].Value
noCount = [NotesDelete].Form![Text50].Value

MsgBox actCount
MsgBox PlaCount
MsgBox noCount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but if you are you trying to active the code upon initialize, then just

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    [your code here...]

End Sub
```

If however, you are trying to populate variables of forms that are not loaded, then a better approach might be to store the variables as public variables in the forms.  This should give you access to the variables even when they are not loaded.  Just as an example of how this might work:

In the form from where you want to get the variable (named UserForm1):

```
Public strFromTheForm As String


Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    TextBox1.Value = strFromTheForm

End Sub
```

From another form or a module, you can include the code:

```
Public Sub Test2()

    Dim strTest As String
    strTest = UserForm1.strFromTheForm

    If strTest = "" Then

        UserForm1.strFromTheForm = "Test"

    End If

    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```